# Call Macro in Excel Sheet with XLWings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong calling macros from Python? If I open the a sheet manually, I can run Macros (via the toolbar) no problem. If I open it programattically, it tells me Macros are disabled!

I have a sheet with a module, as such:

[image: Project Layout]

The module contains the following:

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1").Value = "This is a test."
End Sub
```

Every time I call the method, it fails. Here's what I've tried, along with the errors I got:

## Open Sheet:

```
with xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False) as app:
    wb = app.books.open(r"test1.xlsm")
    ws: xw.Sheet = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
```

## Attempts:

**`wb.macro("test")()`**

- `"Cannot run the macro ''test1.xlsm'!test'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."`

**`app.macro("test")()`**

- `"Cannot run the macro 'test'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."`

**`app.macro("'test1.xlsm'!test")()`**

- `"Cannot run the macro ''test1.xlsm'!test'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."`

**`app.api.Application.run("test")`**

- *Deadlocks*

**`wb.api.Application.run("test")`**

- *Deadlocks*

**`wb.macro('Module1.test')()`**

- `Because of your security settings, macros have been disabled. To run macros, you need to reopen this workbook, and then choose to enable macros.`

## Excel Security

And just in case this is a thought: I enabled *everything* possible in the Trust Center.

[image: Trust Center]